# Cannot set ValueObject as database index along with another table column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I have the following ValueMember

```
public class ApplicationName : ValueObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }

    protected ApplicationName()
    {
    }

    private ApplicationName(string firstName, string lastName)
        : this()
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
    
    etc...
}
```

in the following class (Asp.Net Core IdentityUser)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public ApplicationUserName Name { get; set; }
}
```

Those columns (FirstName, LastName) along with the Email column are part of a db index.
I have the following in my dbcontext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(x =>
{
    x.OwnsOne(p => p.Name, p =>
    {
        p.Property(pp => pp.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        p.Property(pp => pp.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
    });
    x.HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.Email });
});
```

When I run my app I get the following error `System.InvalidOperationException: ''Name' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'ApplicationUser' because it is configured as a navigation.'`

How can I set the index without receiving the above error?

Comment: It seems that current version of EF Core (EF Core 5) does not support this via fluent API. For anyone out there having the same issue here is a link to a workaround by Microsoft guys ```https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11336```